# How to wrap radio button group in label zend form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, radio-group

I want the following html with two radio button groups in zend form

```
        <label class="inline">
        <input type="radio" name="form-field-radio">
    <span class="lbl"> Male</span>
    </label>
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
   <label class="inline">
    <input type="radio" name="form-field-radio">
    <span class="lbl"> Female</span>
   </label>
```

and i'm using the following code to make this button in Zend Form

```
$gender = $this->CreateElement('radio','gender')
        ->addFilter(new Zend_Filter_StringTrim())
        ->setMultiOptions(array('M'=>'Male', 'F'=>'Female'))
        ->setDecorators(array( array('ViewHelper') ));
```

But I don't know where to set the lable and span classes in this code.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether its the perfect method to do this its the first time i am using zend framework, But still here are the steps that i did, if you may find useful:

First I created a custom decorator which extends  `Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract` and saved it in the location `'decorator/My_Form_Decorator.php'`. decorator is a directory created by me in root.

```
.
 /decorator
 /application
```

etc...

Then i included it in a controller. I have read that there are certain methods for adding the decorator like `addPrefixPath()` but for time sake i just included the decorator file in top with `'include "../decorator/My_Form_Decorator.php";'`. Then instead of using the `CreateElement` method i used `Zend_Form_Element`.

The following is the code of custom radio decorator

My_Form_Decorator.php

```
class My_Decorator_RadioInput extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{


    public function render($content)
    {
        $element = $this->getElement();

        $label   = htmlentities($element->getLabel());
        $type = $element->type;
        $name = $element->elemName;
        $multiOptions = $element->multiOptions;
        $labelClass = $element->labelClass;
        $spanClass = $element->spanClass;
        $markup='';

        if(!empty($type) && !empty($name) && !empty($multiOptions)  && is_array($multiOptions)){
         foreach($multiOptions as $key=>$value){
           $markup .='<label class="'.$labelClass.'"><input type="radio" name="'.$name.'" value="'.$key.'"> <span class="'.$spanClass.'">'.$value.'</span></label>';                    
         }
        }
        return $markup;
    }
}
```

and this is the code in my controller function

IndexController.php

```
$decorator = new My_Decorator_RadioInput();
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->setAttrib('id', 'test');
$element   = new Zend_Form_Element('foo', array(
    'elemName'=>'gender',
    'type' =>'radio',
    'multiOptions' => array('M'=>'Male', 'F'=>'Female'),
    'labelClass'=>'inline',
    'spanClass'=>'lbl',
    'decorators' => array($decorator),
));
$form->addElement($element);
$this->view->form = $form;
```

And in view index.phtml

```
echo $this->form
```

Hope this is helpful to you..

Comment: it prints "Male" as "<span class="lbl">Male</span>" on the page.

Comment: so they are escaping the html tags, what about the label class is it added?

Comment: Let me try installing zend. I will  let u know if succeeded

Comment: yes i have. it worked for me. Zend 1.12. What is your output when tried?

Comment: Hi Nouphal, I tried your code line by line and it worked perfectly. Now could you suggest me that how to set the default value Male in your code??

Comment: I am rejecting your answer as this does not allow me to set the default value or by populating the zend form. You only had created the custom radio button by iterating the multiOption array.